# Entity Framework 5 library consumers need entity framework dlls?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a Project "Project.EntityFramework" which contains a context to my db.  When attempting to consume the context from a separate project within the same solution "Project.Business" like:

```
using (var db = new EntityFramework.Entities())
{
    // Code
}
```

I get the compiler error on "using":

```
Error   12  'EntityFramework.Entities': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'   ....
```

Now I can F12 and drill down to the Entities, and see it is implementing IDisposable - I can make this error go away if I put reference dlls to entity framework in "Project.Business" but this is defeating the purpose of what I wanted to accomplish - not having any dependency on EF within my Business layer.

Am I doing something wrong?  Or is this just how it has to be?

Comment: If your business layer doesn't want to have any dependency to EF, then your EF project should return something that has no dependency to EF, returning `Entities` that means you will use the EF objects directly, `DbSet`, `DbContext`, `DbConfiguration`, `Database`, etc... you might want to return something more primitive, like `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on @Spivonious' answer, here is what I did to accomplish the repository pattern on my DbContext - hopefully it's mostly implemented properly :/

```
public interface IFooEntity : IDisposable
{
    IEnumerable<Foo> Get();
}

public class FooRepository : IFooEntity
{
    private readonly Entities _context;

    public FooService()
    {
        this._context = new Entities();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> Get()
    {
        return _context.Foo;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

original code from question:

```
using (var db = new EntityFramework.Entities())
{
    // Code
}
```

changed to:

```
using (var db = new EntityFramework.Repository.FooRepository())
{
    // Code
}
```

this allowed my code in the separate project to use my repository rather than the context itself, allowing the business project to not have to rely on entity framework references.

Comment: Looks good, although I'd throw a ToList() on the return statement in the Get method to make the DB query run right there instead of when you enumerate it the first time. If you do want that behavior, it's customary to return IQueryable instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong. If you want the business layer to not depend on EF, you'll need to wrap access to your DbContext class with something else. The Repository pattern is a popular one.

Comment: could you provide an example of how to accomplish this?  When I attempted to do so using an IDispoable repo, I ran into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue after adding some code and referencing a DLL with the model in it. After some head scratching I realised I hadn't referenced *EntityFramework*. The problem went away after adding that.