# EF6: Have to include in startup project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have three projects: Persistence, Logic and Test.

The Persistence project has EF specific stuff.  The Logic project makes use of a Repository pattern to interact with the Persistence/EF stuff.  The Test project is a generic console that calls up a Logic object and checks that my EF setup is correct.  Normal stuff.

In order to run this, I apparently need to have EF installed on the Test project (and I need to move/copy my App.Config from the EF class lib project to the Test project).

It's fine, it works, but when I get into other component/application layer projects, I don't want to have to include an entire EF reference for these "entry points" that don't ever deal with EF directly.

How to keep EF contained specifically to its "own" project?  Thanks

edit for possible duplicate: the possible duplicate deals with how to decouple the business logic from the DAL.  My question deals with why the presentation project requires a reference to Entity Framework: I already have the BAL/DAL segregated and a repository pattern in place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 5 library consumers need entity framework dlls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208243/entity-framework-5-library-consumers-need-entity-framework-dlls)

Comment: Including your sample code and the specific issue you're trying to solve might go a long way - I think the problem you're describing closely resembles the problem I was having with EF in the linked question.

Comment: I don't see this as is a possible duplicate: you're trying to find out how to decouple business/dal projects, I'm trying to find out why my decoupled startup project still needs an EF reference even though it doesn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should limit the dependency of the Entity framework frame work to the minimum amount as possible. The best way to do it is to use EF only in the layer /Project where you have the data access code (Your Data access layer). It is better if you return DTO'/POCO's (Not Entities created by EF) to whoever calling those Data Access methods (Usually from Your Business Layer). You may keep this DTO's in a seperate project ( Let's call it `YourProject.Common`). With this approach, you can always switch your DAL layer to use another data access approach (NHibernate , Pure ADO.NET etc..). If you are using Entity framework, You still need to keep the Connection string (for EF, with all those metadata stuff :( ) in your startup project.

So your Layers/Projects will be something like this

- **Common** ( Will have all the DTO/POCO's)
- **DataAccess** ( Will have the Data access code, This refer the
  YourProject.Common Project and return DTOs from that project. ***You don't need to keep the connection string in this project for your app to run*** as this will be called always from the startup project, which has the connection string. But, keep the `App.Config` (Generated by EF) as it is because you need that when you update your EDMX files later for db changes.
- **Business** ( BL layer, This project will have 2 project references,
  The Common Project and Data Access project)
- **Web/Win forms** ( This is your front end/Startup project.
  This will not directly talk to the Data Access, This will have 2
  project references , Common and Data Access). This will have your connection string.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question.  I actually have multiple applications/FEs on this solution, and my intent is to NOT have to include connection strings (and the entire EF reference overhead) on each presentation project.  As you say, EF should be limited to only where's it's actually needed.  Why does my startup project (in this case, the Test) need it, and how do I circumvent that so EF is isolated to it's EF project?

Comment: You should have the conn string in your startup project as your dal code will be executed from that context. If you have multiple FE projects in your solution. You can create one connectionsting.config file and refer the same file in all your FE projects and update your web configs to use the connectionsting.config file.

Comment: So each FE project, despite being on the opposite end from the bottom persistence layer, must have their own connection strings?  As if I'd want a web API to connect to one database and an internal processor to connect to a different one?  This seems ridiculous in terms of SoC.  Is there really no way get this persistence detail out of the FE layers?  Even if not, my Test (FE) project still requires EF references, not just a connection string.  Thanks

Comment: Connection string in web.configs is perfectly normal.  You may be using the same binaries for your persistence layer that is called by a different front end, but each front end might require a completely separate database.  For instance, the same site deployed twice would potentially have a Test connection string vs a Production connection string.  This is almost always a presentation layer concern.  Optionally you could create a webapi layer that exposes functions to be consumed by the presentation layer where the WebApi service layer has the connection string instead.